# Ideal input size of CNN given training data

Tags: conv-neural-network

Should the input size of the CNN follow that of the training data ? For example, if my training data is of size 192 x 98 then what should the input size of my CNN be ? 192 x 192 ? 98 x 98 ? Would it be a bad idea if I use a 32x32 input CNN ?

I have sooooo many questions on the specifics of CNN but no one has the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary that the input size of the CNN should be the same as that of the training data.

What input size to choose depends on what application you are using the CNN for. For example, for classification, a 32x32 image might give a good accuracy. But for something like segmentation, it will most probably not give a good output. That being said, using a higher resolution image will result in a slightly higher accuracy. Refer this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02876). So, if you afford the extra processing time, go for the higher resolution.

Comment: Say if I were to maintain an aspect ration of 16:9 in my data and the original image size (1920x1080) is too big to train due to limited resources, should I pick any dimension that I can train? i,e, Will 256x144 (powers of 2) have any advantages over 400x225 image? (I will get more resolution, but have not seen this type of dimension in literature a lot)